# A filter to remove dynamic F0 and lower harmonics

Tags: filter, programming, speech, harmonics

I'm studying the perception of vowel formants and need to create stimuli where the signal below the first formant is removed. I have some naturalistic vowels (also a requirement for this study) which inevitably have a dynamic pitch curve (first spectrogram on the left in the picture). This means that using a fixed threshold high-pass filter will leave more harmonics in some sections of the stimulus, but I would like to avoid that.

Is there a way to specify a dynamic threshold for the filter, for example to make it follow a pre-determined F0 curve? Perhaps removing even some higher harmonics?

Thanks.

[image: Left: unfiltered vowel. Middle: F0 removed. Right: F0 and first harmonic removed.]

Comment: A pitch follower would be needed to accomplish this.  It would tell you exactly what f0 was from moment to moment, and that information could be used to continuously retune your filter.  (Hence, this question is better suited for dsp.stackexchange.com, where there are experts in this.)

Comment: Thank you! I will check with dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hi Renata. You can get answers here, but it would be from a sound engineer or digital sound designer's perspective. Like, I'd suggest using NI Reaktor or something similar to track F0 and control an LPF's cutoff freq with the CV. It should work with some simple maths. Or you could do it manually with a freq selector tool. If this is not the kind of answer you're looking for, if you want more science or code or something, I'll close this question as being "not clear" so it's not left hanging here. Thanks.